# mhchem formatting interrupted

Tags: formatting, mhchem

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{K_a \times K_b = K_w}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In `\ce{}` all text is supposed to be regularized.  See how the `K_a` is regularized but then the `K_b` is italicised and the ensuing `K_w` is again subject to `\ce`'s regularization.  Why does this interruption in formatting happen?  I mean, it probably has to do with the `\times`, but then why does italicised formatting resume after that?

Comment: Equilibrium constants are not chemical symbols but normal mathematical variables. The should simply be typeset as such, i.e., in math mode and in italics `$K_a \times K_b = K_w$`. For reference see page 58 of IUPAC Green Book (third edition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why it happened, but you can fix it by placing the `\times` around in a `$..$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{K_a \times K_b = K_w}

\ce{K_a ${}\times{}$ K_b = K_w}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To keep the proper math spacing I added `{}` to make the times a binary operator. Alternatively you could use `\ce{K_a \mathbin{\times} K_b = K_w}`, but I prefer the `{}`.

Comment: It's documented (See page 8 of the documentation).

Comment: Um, about the `{}` to make the times a binary operator, I'm not sure I understand.  Can you please explain?

Comment: Binary operator in the math sense. Best to have a look at the difference spacing between the times symbols in `$A \times B$ and `$\times B$.  Or, try taking out the `{}` in the solution and see what happens.  If this still is not clear, perhaps you should post a question.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply enclose `\times` in braces:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{K_a {\times} K_b = K_w}
\end{document}
```

[image]